# Starting and stopping subprocess with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to start and stop a program on a device through `MQTT` commands, but it's not really working out the way I'm hoping..

To start the process, I'm using:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "process.sh"])
```

Which works out fine, it starts the program.

Further down the line in the code I'm trying to kill/terminate the program with either `p.kill` or `p.terminate` but it's returning the code:

```
p.terminate()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment
```

The code I'm working with is my own, and goes as follows:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        if msg.payload == "start":
                p = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "stream.sh"])
        if msg.payload == "stop":
                p.terminate()
```

Comment: If `on_message` is callback function, it does not remember previous invocation. You need to store reference to `p` somewhere and retrieve it in subsequent function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = None

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global p
    if msg.payload == "start":
            p = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "stream.sh"])
    if msg.payload == "stop" and p:
            p.terminate()
```

Comment: In-case you want to know a further why this problem occurred [this](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) can be a good read.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define p as global

```
def on_message(...):
    global p
```